Explain AWS S3 Glacier Storage Class charges
My team have been trying to store many small object (approx 10kB) using the AWS S3 Glacier Storage Class and have found that it is costing dramatically more than just storing the objects in the Standard Storage Class.
It's not clear from the AWS S3 Pricing Page where these charges are coming from.The AWS Pricing Calculator does provide more information but it still lacks an explanation for them.
For example, for S3 Glacier Storage Class, the Pricing Calculator gives the following data for storing 100 GB per month with an Average Object Size of 10kB:
Unit conversions
S3 Glacier Deep Archive Average Object Size: 10 KB x 9.5367432e-7 GB in a KB = 0.0000095367432 GB

Pricing calculations
100 GB per month / 0.0000095367432 GB average item size = 10,485,759.9605 unrounded number of objects
Round up by 1 (10485759.9605) = 10485760 number of objects
10,485,760 number of objects x 32 KB = 335,544,320.00 KB overhead
335,544,320.00 KB overhead / 1048576 KB in a GB = 320.00 GB overhead
320.00 GB overhead x 0.00099 USD = 0.3168 USD (Glacier Deep Archive storage overhead cost for metadata)
Glacier Deep Archive storage overhead cost: 0.3168 USD
10,485,760 number of objects x 8 KB = 83,886,080.00 KB overhead
83,886,080.00 KB overhead / 1048576 KB in a GB = 80.00 GB overhead
Tiered price for: 80.00 GB
80 GB x 0.023 USD = 1.84 USD
Total tier cost = 1.84 USD (S3 Standard storage overhead cost)
S3 Standard storage overhead cost: 1.84 USD
100 GB per month x 0.00099 USD = 0.099 USD (Glacier Deep Archive storage cost)
Glacier Deep Archive storage cost: 0.099 USD
0.3168 USD + 1.84 USD + 0.099 USD = 2.2558 USD (Total Glacier Deep Archive storage cost)
S3 Glacier Deep Archive cost (monthly): 2.26 USD

I'm struggling to make sense of this.
It mentions "overhead cost". The internet suggests this is the cost of storing metadata about the objects being stored. But why 2 bits of metadata (one 32 KB and the other 8KB)? Why is there a charge for Standard Storage use when I'm storing in the Glacier Class?
Could someone please provide more details around these additional costs? Or point me in the right direction if I've missed something in the AWS Docs?

The S3 pricing page has three stars *** beside the glacier pricing. Looking at the notes they currently starts as below
In short, you're paying for 40kb of extra storage per object. I suggest you compress your files into archives such as zip files and continue to use Glacier storage classes, or use a storage class with less overhead such as S3 Standard.

For each object that is stored in the S3 Glacier Flexible Retrieval
and S3 Glacier Deep Archive storage classes, AWS charges for 40 KB of
for index and metadata, with 8 KB charged at S3 Standard rates and 32
KB charged at S3 Glacier Flexible Retrieval or S3 Deep Archive rates.
This allows you to get a real-time list of all of your S3 objects
using the S3 LIST API or the S3 Inventory report. S3 Glacier Instant
Retrieval has a minimum billable object size of 128 KB. Smaller
objects may be stored but will be charged for 128 KB of storage at the
appropriate storage class rate.


D'Oh! Sorry, didn't spot that. But you are quite right. Thanks.

Please accept the answer if you're happy with it, so others can see your question has been answered :)
